# iterate over matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have following problem:

I delete entries when in both matrices they are zero. If I have i pairs of such matrices, how to properly write indexing for the loop in matlab here?
code:

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 5 0 7 0]
y = [0 2 0 1 1 2 5 2 7 0]

idx = ~(x==0 & y==0);

x2 = x(idx)
y2 = y(idx)
```

can you help me?

Comment: what's your problem? what loop are you talking about? Do you want to know the indices of elements of `x2` in the original vector `x`?

Comment: Whoops, I upvoted this question by mistake.  And I don't actually want to downvote it.

Comment: the answer I voted solves the problem, it was rare though. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to match elements where both x and y are zero, so something like this should work (without the not `~`):

```
idx = (x==0 & y==0);

x2 = x(~idx)
y2 = y(~idx)
```

#### Edit

Or more simply, as suggested by mutzmatron:

```
idx = (x ~= 0 | y ~= 0);

x2 = x(idx)
y2 = y(idx)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - OP wants to **delete** entries where both are 0, so you probably want to change `idx` to `~idx`.

Comment: Right, got it inverted. Updated the answer.

Comment: not totally necessary, but why not put the `~` in the definition  - `idx = ~(...` instead (one call) instead of at each index (two calls).

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps ?

```
x2 = x(find(or((x~=0),(y~=0))))
y2 = y(find(or((x~=0),(y~=0))))
```

These, obviously, don't do an in-place replacement, so `x` and `y` are not changed. I haven't figured out how to do that on both arrays simultaneously yet.

**EDIT** Read @mutzmatron's comments below

Comment: Also as in @Thor's answer, you don't need to use `find`, use logical indexing (i.e. just removing find accesses `x` and `y` using logical arrays).

Comment: Actually Thor's answer is still wrong - OP wants to **delete** 0 entries, so you're answer is the only correct one, but logical indexing can be much faster than using the additional call to find.